# Calculus - Calculate Work done to lift water out of tank

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, applications, word-problem

[image]

I need help setting up the integral so that I can calculate the work done. I've tried it many times and have referred to Youtube, slader, the textbook, and also this site, but I still don't get how to solve it. I came up with a few solutions but they were all wrong. Please help, I've been at this for 2 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $P(x)$ is wrong because you took the base to be the top face, presumably because it is larger than the bottom face.  The base is the bottom face.  Instead of $5-(2/3)x$ it should be $3+(2/3)x$.  Good on you for using parentheses.  I didn't do the second part.

Comment: thank you so much, I figured out the second part. If I needed to calculate the work done, would my integral be bound between $[0,4]$? I tried this bound, but it is always incorrect and I do not understand why, because it's the distance the water must be lifted

Comment: You don't show your integral, so I cannot be sure, but I would think the integral would be over $[0,3]$ because that is the water in the tank.  You need to account for the extra meter in the work done for each layer, but there are only $3$ meters of layers.

Comment: the integral is not required, but I just want to know how I could solve it for future reference if it were a question being tested. For my integral, I wrote $9800*pi*((3+(2/3)x)^2)(4-x)$ to be integrated (it's my answer from second part).

Comment: So do I need to account for that 1 meter where the spout sticks out? I understand that there are only 3 meters of layers, but what happens to the 1m? Is it not necessary to calculate?

Comment: You have that $1$ meter in your $4-x$ factor.  That is the distance you lift the layer.  If the spout were at the top of the reservoir it would be $3-x$.  You are off a factor $4$ because $3+(2/3)x$ is the diameter, not the radius.

Comment: so the integral is bounded by $[0,3]$ and the integral is $9800∗pi∗((3+(2/3)x)2)(4−x)$? Sorry I just want to confirm if I am understanding the problem correctly. I really appreciate your help so far, thank you so much

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, thank you!